# Ошибка при удалении бинарного дерева поиска

Tags: c, visual-c++

Всем привет. Помогите найти ошибку при удалении дерева.
Сама функция удаления выглядит так:

```
void DeleteNode(Node *node)
{
    if ( node == NULL ) return;
    DeleteNode( node->left );
    DeleteNode( node->right );
    free( node );
}

void DeteleTree(Tree *t)
{
    DeleteNode( t->root );
    free( t );
}
```

Ее вызов производится следующим образом: `DeteleTree( derevo );`.

Вылетает она при удалении указателя на `Node`. При вылете пишет это:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#281) at 0x00810B60.
>
> CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Весь код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32;

struct Node
{
    uint32 data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

struct Tree
{
    Node *root;
    uint32 count;
};

Tree* CreateTree(void)
{
    Tree *temp = (Tree*)malloc( sizeof( Tree ) );
    temp->count = 0;
    temp->root = NULL;
    return temp;
}

uint32 Search(Tree *SearchTree, uint32 item)
{
    Node *temp = SearchTree->root;
    while (1)
    {
        if ( temp == NULL ) return 0;
        else if ( item == temp->data ) return 1;
        else if ( item < temp->data ) temp = temp->left;
        else temp = temp->right;
    }
}

bool AddNewNode(Tree *SearchTree, uint32 item)
{
    Node *temp = SearchTree->root, **newroot = &SearchTree->root;

    if ( Search( SearchTree, item ) ) return false;

    while (1)
    {
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            temp = *newroot = (Node*)malloc( sizeof( Tree ) );
            temp->data = item;
            temp->left = NULL;
            temp->right = NULL;
            SearchTree->count++;
            return 1;
        }
        else if (item > temp->data)
        {
            newroot = &temp->right;
            temp = temp->right;
        }
        else
        {
            newroot = &temp->left;
            temp = temp->left;
        }
    }
}

void PrintTree(Node *node)
{
    if ( node == NULL ) return;
    PrintTree( node->left );
    printf( "%d ", node->data );
    PrintTree( node->right );
}

void DeleteNode(Node *node)
{
    if ( node == NULL ) return;
    DeleteNode( node->left );
    DeleteNode( node->right );
    free( node );
}

void DeteleTree(Tree *t)
{
    DeleteNode( t->root );
    free( t );
}

int main(void)
{
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "Russian" );
    Tree *derevo = CreateTree();
    uint32 newitem;

    while (1)
    {
        system( "cls" );
        PrintTree( derevo->root );
        printf( "\n\n1)Add new\n2)Exit" );
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case '1':
            system( "cls" );
            printf( "New item = " );
            scanf( "%d", &newitem );
            if ( !AddNewNode( derevo, newitem ) )
            {
                printf( "\nThis item in tree" );
                _getch();
            }
            break;

        case '2':
            DeteleTree( derevo );
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательней надо:

```
temp = *newroot = (Node*)malloc( sizeof( Tree ) );
```

Очевидно, имелось в виду:

```
temp = *newroot = (Node*)malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
```

P.S. А что при равенстве item и данных узла всё пойдёт налево - это так задумано?

Comment: Черт, как же я мог это не заметить... Спасибо!

Comment: Да, так задумано) Но одинаковых функция поиска не допустит

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) прекрасно подсвечивает именно эту строку, и уже после этой подсказки проще разбираться. Судя по коду - Windows, но и под них [есть аналоги](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows), очень полезная штука.